# Android - If I try a function, will I catch NullPointerExceptions?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, try-catch

Can I do this:

```
 try {
        loadItem();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry, we couldn't load that item. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And catch any NullPointerExceptions that might occur in loadItem()?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Why not test it yourself by throwing a `NullPointerException` in that method?

Comment: you could have tried this before asking here

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Unless `loadItem()` itself catches the exception without rethrowing, it will bubble up to the caller.

You can test this out with the following program, which outputs `Ouch!` due to the exception handler kicking in:

```
public class DodgyProg {
    public static void loadItem() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            loadItem();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Ouch!");
        }
    }
}
```